# Click on button without id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How click button in webdriver without any id, values. Class of button is changing dynamically. 
Sample:

```
<div class="d-k-l d-y-r-c g-h-f-Ck b-Qb" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true">

    <div class="d-k-l d-y-r-c-ha">

        Мои круги

    </div>
    <div class="d-k-l d-y-r-c-Qa"></div>

</div>
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Show more HTML please. So that we can find something useful in the context.

Currently the only possible way is to use XPath' `text()`

```
.//*[@role='button']/*[contains(text(), 'Мои круги')]
```

If you are sure relevant elements are `div`, you can use

```
.//div[@role='button']/div[contains(text(), 'Мои круги')]
```

Comment: use `div[@role='button']/div[contains(text(), 'Мой круги')]`  Don't specify `*` unless you don't know what element it's going to be.  Xpath is very slow using this type of selector!

Comment: @sircapsalot: Yes, that's what I would do. But generally I don't trust OPs' HTML, they tend to simplify their snippets and give unreal ones  for some reason. Giving XPath with wildcard in SO answers is just in case OPs have no idea what XPath is and won't bother learning. I met situations like this a lot.

Comment: fair enough i guess `:)`

Comment: @user3172706: Since you're a new user and never accepted any answers before. Just so you know if this fixes your issue, please accept http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697, otherwise provide some feedback here.